# Test Kotlin Coroutines with runBlockingTest{} failed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotest

I have created a simple Micronaut Kotlin Coroutines example want to write tests with `kotlin-corotines-test`. I have added the `kotlin-corotines-test` in dependencies.

I tried to use `runBlockingTest`, and the following test(Kotest/FuncSpec) failed.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `test GET all posts endpoint`() = runBlockingTest {
    val response = client.exchange("/posts", Array<Post>::class.java).awaitSingle()

    response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
    response.body()!!.map { it.title }.forAny {
        it shouldContain "Micronaut"
    }
}
```

And throw exceptions like this.

```sh
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet
    at kotlinx.coroutines.JobSupport.getCompletionExceptionOrNull(JobSupport.kt:1190)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest(TestBuilders.kt:53)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runBlockingTest$default(TestBuilders.kt:45)
    at com.example.ApplicationTest.test GET posts endpoint(ApplicationTest.kt:30)
```

But if use `runBlocking` in the fun body, it works.

```kotlin
@Test
fun `test GET all posts endpoint`() {
    runBlocking {
        val response = client.exchange("/posts", Array<Post>::class.java).awaitSingle()

        response.status shouldBe HttpStatus.OK
        response.body()!!.map { it.title }.forAny {
            it shouldContain "Micronaut"
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: get the solution from issue [Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#1204](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204), update to kotlin coroutine to 1.6.0-RC to resolve it, and use `runTest` instead of the deprecated `runBlockingTest`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and you can check [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1204).

Just to document it here as well, there are few workarounds as:

- Use InstantTaskExecutorRule

```
@get:Rule
val instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

- Use runBlocking

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlocking {
    coroutineJob.join()
}
```

- Make sure you call from your test dispatcher instance

```
coroutineRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest{...}
```

Comment: I am using Kotest in this sample project.